# Make COM Interop Events visible from Interface

Tags: c#, events, com, interop

I wrote my code like the example below:

```
public delegate void ClickDelegate(int x, int y);
public delegate void PulseDelegate();

[Guid("39D5B254-64DB-4130-9601-996D0B20D3E5"),
InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IButton
{
  void Work();
}

// Step 1: Defines an event sink interface (ButtonEvents) to be     
// implemented by the COM sink.
[GuidAttribute("1A585C4D-3371-48dc-AF8A-AFFECC1B0967") ]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface ButtonEvents
{
    void Click(int x, int y);
    void Pulse();
}

// Step 2: Connects the event sink interface to a class 
// by passing the namespace and event sink interface.
// ("EventSource.ButtonEvents, EventSrc").
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ButtonEvents))]
public class Button : IButton
{
    public event ClickDelegate Click;
    public event PulseDelegate Pulse;

    public Button() { }

    public void CauseClickEvent(int x, int y) { Click(x, y); }
    public void CausePulse() { Pulse(); }

    public void Work() { /* Do some stuff */ }
}
```

This works fine with VB. When I define it like:

```
Dim WithEvents obj As Button
```

But I want to define it with the Interface like:

```
Dim WithEvents obj As IButton
```

This is not working 'cause the events are not visible from the IButton interface.

**Is there a way to do this?**

Comment: No, in a type library, the source (or event) interfaces are declared for a coclass.

Comment: Excellent example, which helped me immensely in migrating a VB6 user control to managed code.

Answer (score 1):

A variable that connects to an object's events must be declared to be of the type (CoClass) of the object (`Button` in your example). An interface (`IButton` in your example) doesn't know anything about the events, and it cannot be used to request them.

This is the way I like to think about it:

> An interface is something two objects agree on using so the "client" can send commands to the "server" (*"server, do XYZ!"*). An Event is just a different interface that the two objects also agree on using, but *for the opposite*: that is, for the "server" object to send commands to the "client".

Whether a given Event interface is supported is a property of the object, not a property of whatever interface(s) the object might support. The server object says: *"Give me a `ButtonEvents` interface pointer, and I'll use it to tell you when the button has been clicked"*. It's not the `IButton` interface that makes that offer.

That's also why you have to apply the `[ComSourceInterfaces]` attribute to the class `Button`, not to the interface `IButton`. The `Button` CoClass is the one that makes the offer.

The thing that makes events look special or weird is that we need to use a somewhat complicated and confusing dance ("Connection Points") to pass the event's interface pointer around. `WithEvents` is the way to ask VB6 to "do the dance" for you.